# Should it call method hasKey before get when use redis or other DB

Tags: java, redis

When I want to get data form Redis, I was confused about that whether or not call method redis.hasKey before redis.get.

Someone write like this:

```
if (redis.hasKey('xxx')) {
    return redis.get('xxx');
}
return ...
```

and the others write like this:

```
Object value = redis.get('xxx')
if (value != null) {
    return value
}
return ...
```

I think the second one was good, because it just once Redis operation, the first one has two. Which did you choose and why? Thanks.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to hasKey is blocking and so is get. It makes much more sense to just call get and check if the result is null or *empty* depending on the object.

Comment: So, you choose the second one?

Comment: Absolutely. It's more efficient.